# How to write 8085 program to generate square wave,sawtooth, sine, triangular wave and ramp using DAC?

Tags: 8085

Edit-: I understood all programs now.

I want a general idea to write these programs. I know how to write square wave, as well as I know triangular wave. But I am not clear with them.
I am unable to get how this program is creating triangular wave?

I can't see how would this create a triangular wave though I understand what is exactly going on with syntax.

I will explain continous ramp waveform and my confusions.

Accumulator=0000 0000

DTOA-:
printf("DAC output=00)
B=count

DELAY-:
Decrease count
if count not zero loop DELAY. i.e keep delaying unless required count is fulfilled.

if count zero-:
Accumulator=Accumulator+1
Go to DTOA
[image]

Program for triangular wave-:

[image]

I understand each and every line of this program. But I don't understand how is this forming a traingular wave. I even have program trace.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

But what I don't understand here is how the wave goes to x axis. IMO the program should make a straight line from 00 to FF and another straight line from FF to 00, how is it making a traingular wave? It is out of my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are *two* main code loops in the program: the POS section increments until it reachs FFh. After that the NEG section decrements until it goes back to 00h.

The last jump to start could be have written as jmp POS since it's already at zero :D

Comment: I understand them one is for value from 00 to FF and another from FF to 00, but what I don't understand how does computer knows what is the x axis value? I don't see that x axis value changing here? Does it happens automatically? The y axis value I know from code. I know all basics of programming.

Comment: the x axis is simply the time! the fact that it's doing sequential execution well… takes time

Comment: Oh I see I actually guessed that. This is why I hate programming and driving, in both cases you don't have to overthink and just go with the flow. Makes sense now. I understood all waveforms easily now, it was my only confusion. Thanks a lot.